# Canvas - How to save user input in an object?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have a application, where users can draw strokes on the canvas. How can I save the input, so that it is repainted after I cleared the canvas to erease for example rects that have been added. I used an array but it really takes long after a while to repaint all the array entries.

my code to realize strokes look similar to this: http://jsfiddle.net/FgNQk/1/

```
var points[];
 var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var width  = window.innerWidth;
var height = window.innerHeight;
canvas.height = height;
canvas.width = width;
canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
    this.down = true;   
    this.X = e.pageX ;
    this.Y = e.pageY ;
    this.color = rgb();
}, 0);
canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
    this.down = false;          
}, 0);
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {

    if(this.down) {
         with(ctx) {
            beginPath();
            moveTo(this.X, this.Y);
            lineTo(e.pageX , e.pageY );
            strokeStyle = "rgb(0,0,0)";
            ctx.lineWidth=1;
            stroke();

            // saving via array
             if (this.down) {

             points.push({x:e.pageX,y:e.pageY});

     }
         }
         this.X = e.pageX ;
         this.Y = e.pageY ;
    }
}, 0);
```

Comment: Yo can save it as an image. then restore the image to your canvas surface. Does it solve your problem ?

Comment: Could you show what you tried allready to store / display user input ? What is your goal / the level of flexibility you expect ?

Comment: @Siamak.A.M but how if there pixels on the canvas I do not want. A user puts rects/etc on the canvas and strokes but I only want to save the strokes

Comment: @VincentPiel I added the array I currently use to push all the strokes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to build several abstraction layers to avoid major 
headache in your code.

I just built a small 'Drawer' class which keep the user context,
to remember what is he drawing, color, ... and the current list
of all drawn things.
Then you need  some classes to store line, rect, ... data

On each move of the mouse, the whole scene gets redrawn, which
will works fast enough on most devices/browser i think.

http://jsfiddle.net/ZS34V/1/

```
var Drawer = function () {
  this.currentFigureType = 0 ;  // 0 : free draw, 1 : line,
                              // 2 : square, ...
  this.currentFigure = null  ;  
  this.figures       = [] ;
  this.currentColor  = 0  ;
  this.startX        = 0  ;
  this.startY        = 0  ;       
  this.lastX        = 0  ;
  this.lastY        = 0  ;       
  this.mouseDown     = false;  }

Drawer.prototype.draw = function(ctx) {
    var figuresArray = this.figures;
    for (var i=0, len=figuresArray.length; i < len; i++) {
        figuresArray[i].draw(ctx);
    }
 }
```

And now on the mouse up/down/move, we will check the context and act accordingly : start a new figure on mousedown, update it on mousemove, and store it on mouseup.

```
canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
        myDrawer.startX = e.pageX  ;
        myDrawer.startY = e.pageY  ;
        myDrawer.mouseDown = true ;

        switch (myDrawer.currentFigureType) {
          case  0 : break;
           case 1 : break ;
        }

    }, 0);

 canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
        myDrawer.mouseDown = false
        switch (myDrawer.currentFigureType) {
          case  0 : break;
          case 1 :  var newLine = new Line(myDrawer.currentColor,
                                            myDrawer.startX,
                                            myDrawer.startY,
                                            myDrawer.lastX,
                                            myDrawer.lastY);
                    myDrawer.figures.push(newLine);
                    break ;
        }

}, 0);


canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {

  if(!myDrawer.mouseDown) { return }

  myDrawer.lastX = e.pageX; 
  myDrawer.lastY=e.pageY;

  ctx.clearRect(0,0,width, height);
  myDrawer.draw(ctx);
  switch (myDrawer.currentFigureType) {
          case  0 :   // draw + store point
                    break;
           case 1 :
             with(ctx) {
                 console.log('we here');
                        beginPath();
                        moveTo(myDrawer.startX, myDrawer.startY);
                        lineTo(e.pageX , e.pageY );
                        strokeStyle = myDrawer.currentColor;
                        ctx.lineWidth=1;
                        stroke();
                     }
                    break;
            }
    }, 0);
```

Comment: thx, but your jsfiddle is not containing the code of your answer